# Push a new repo to an existing Heroku app and overwrite what is there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have deployed a Rails 6 app to Heroku about 3 months ago. This was just a temporary website whilst I was creating the app. Now I want to push the new app to the existing Heroku app and overwrite whatever is already there, including a new database. How do I do that? The code is in a different repo locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI you can do the following:

- Add heroku as your remote on your new project
- git push --force heroku master
- connect to web console on heroku, drop database and recreate-it.

However, deleting the existing application and recreating it is simpler.

Comment: It was a lot easier just deleting it and recreating another. Thanks.